# Include +1 -1 around value considered as equal to compare two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is the development of this one: [Identify value in 1 column corresponding to equal values in two another columns by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160257/identify-value-in-1-column-corresponding-to-equal-values-in-two-another-columns)

So, I would  like to identify the value of row in V1 depending on values in columns V2 and V3. My previous question was looking how to identify the value in V1 if the V2 = V3. However, I would like to implement the interval + - 1 around the values thus consider as equal values V2 + 1 = V3. Please, how can I include this condition?

Here is my code:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,5,6,
              1,10,0,10,3,
              1,11,3,8,2), 5, 3) 
df1<-as.data.frame(m) 

> df1
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1    1
2  2  10  11
3  3  0    3
4  5  10   8
5  6  3    2
```

using the df1[df1$V2 == df1$V3, ] I can have the equal values, but how to include the + - 1 interval? thus for equal will be considered also rows 2 (10 11) and 5 (3 2).

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1[abs(df1$V2 - df1$V3) <= 1,]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  1  1
#2  2 10 11
#5  6  3  2
```

Use `abs` to check the absolute value of the difference between the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: Thank you !! I was sure there is a simple solution :) I hope I will remember this idea for the next time :)